# Will Publishers Accept Alternate Planetology?

Tags: publishing

I am planning to write a novel that is set in a solar system where the 1950's tropes are its reality. This means that my story is set on a Venus where lush, fertile jungles cover the majority of the planet. Will publishers still accept the alternative planet despite not being scientifically accurate? It is fiction...

Comment: Why exactly is this of concern? As long as you sell it as Science Fantasy rather than Science Fiction, I doubt anyone would even bat an eye.

Answer (score 7):

Publishers will accept anything that they think people will buy. That is all ye know on earth and all ye need to know.